# Targeting a hover element in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, hover

I know this is probably a recipe for disaster, but I want to change a css:hover element after scrolling 150 px. I'm already using jQuery to do this, but I don't know how to target the hover element. Any solution?

My code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if ( $(window).scrollTop() > 150 ) {
      $('#menu li ul li:hover').css('background', 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';
   } else {
      $('#menu li ul li:hover').css('background', 'rgba(255,255,255,0.3)');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re making it too hard on yourself. For styling, use classes.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('#menu').toggleClass('special', $(window).scrollTop() > 10);
});
```

Now, the class `special` is applied on `#menu` when the user has scrolled at least 10 pixels. That class can be used for styling:

```
#menu.special li ul li {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

#menu.special li ul li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Comment: Can I use EM as the measurement instead of PX? I imagine this would be better when viewing the site on different devices.

Comment: The height applied to the body was just for that demo, if that is what you mean. I don’t recommend it using in your project.

Comment: But is it possible to use 2em instead of 10px?

Comment: 1em is usually ~16px, so you may want to use 0.625em for 10px. But yeah, you can replace all pixel values with em’s :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the style of a pseudo class like that, instead use a class based solution like

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('#menu').toggleClass('scrolled', $(window).scrollTop() > 10);
});
```

then

```
#menu.scrolled li ul li:hover {
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
#menu li ul li:hover {
    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('#menu').toggleClass('scrolled', $(window).scrollTop() > 10);
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}
#menu.scrolled li ul li:hover {
  background: green;
}
#menu li ul li:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery cannot amend psuedo selectors used in CSS. However, you could use jQuery to add/remove a class from the element and hang the CSS `:hover` state from that. Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var method = $(this).scrollTop() > 10 ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass';
    $('#menu li ul li:hover')[method]('scrolled');
});
```

```css
#menu li ul li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
#menu li ul li.scrolled:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Comment: With this method I have to hover my cursor over the element and scroll at the same time for it to work. I simply want the hover background to change when I'm halfway down the page.

Comment: `With this method I have to hover my cursor over the element and scroll at the same time` that's not true at all - it will work as soon as the page is scrolled down by 10 pixels

Answer (score 0):

On scroll change the classname. 
Inside your CSS, setup that class with the desired styling.

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/jogira/1/edit?html,css,js,output)***

For example:

```
var $menuLi2 = $('#menu li ul li'); // Cache your selectors

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
   $menuLi2.toggleClass( "winScrolled", $(this).scrollTop() > 150 );
});
```

CSS:

```
#menu li ul li:hover{ background: rgba(0,0,0,1); }
#menu li ul li.winScrolled:hover{ background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `class` attribute.

```
.myNewHoverClass:hover{
   background: ..... !important;
}


$('element selector').addClass('myNewHoverClass')
```

The `!important;` syntax after the css rule is that it is applied with first priority, you can avoid it if you make your style smarter.

or

```
    .myHoverClass:hover{
       background: ..... ;
    }
    .myNewHoverClass:hover{
       background: ..... ;
    }

$('element selector').removeClass('myHoverClass').addClass('myNewHoverClass')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the jQuery .hover() method. Get a variable in there which changes on scroll :)

```
$('#menu li ul li').hover( function() {
    /* Code what happens on hover */
}, function() {
    /* Code what happens on stop hover */
});
```